# query multiple tables but get results from any one of the tables without JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

description of my 2 tables:

```
table1
id (int),
bid (int),
trs (varchar 10)

table2
id (int),
bid (int),
ref_table (varchar 10)
trs (varchar 10)

br 
id    bid     trs
1     213     1913
2     2174    1920

bt 
id    bid     ref_table   trs 
1     212     room        1913 
2     214     room        1920
```

i want the output as only 1 row from br where bid = 2174

I want to query both the tables on bid and get the matching rows.
a particular bid can be in any one table, cant exists in both tables.

```
SELECT bt.*, br.* FROM bt, br where br.bid = 2174 OR bid = 2174
```

but this give me matching rows from one table + all the rows from other table.
please suggest.

since i am trying to do this in mysql, tagging mysql also

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  And what does this mean?  "cant exists in both tables."  Is that a condition of your search or is that how the data is laid out?

Comment: Hi. You are not clear about what result you want. Eg what does "get the matching rows" mean, since the tables have rows with different columns? Also in a comment on an answer you say "is there any way to fetch all the columns of the table that matched the condition"; that's not clear either. Please do not clarify in comments, edit your post. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `union all` does what you want:

```
select id, bid, trs, null as ref_table
from br
where bid = 2174
union all
select id, bid, trs, ref_table
from bt
where bid = 2174;
```

Comment: actually table columns are more and diverse, is there any way to fetch all the columns of the table that matched the condition?

Comment: @Gunnrryy . . . Just include the appropriate columns in each subquery.  If you still need help, ask *another* question.

Comment: @Gunnrryy . . . Is there a reason that you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I am really sorry i didn't pay enough attention to the answer, this does solve my issue. but i had done something else due to time issue.